# how to insert value to database that is fetched by jquery using json autocomplete in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, database

To whom it may respond to,

We are trying to insert the data to Oracle DBMS, fetched by JSON by calling asp.net webservices.
Here,aspx page is the modified code from another stackoverflow answer. Do we have to use JSON again to send the values to codebehind ? If so, how? 
Thanks to http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Jquery-JSON-Add-Edit-Update-Delete-in-Asp-Net for sample scripts

Thank you for your concern

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="test7._Default" %>
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
        <div id="outer" style="width: 100%; background-color: #737CA1">
            <div id="HeadDiv" style="width: 90%; background-color: #737CA1">
                <script type="text/javascript" id="ButceList">
                    $(function () {
                        $("#txtButce").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                var param = { prefixText: $('#txtButce').val() };
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "Default.aspx/GetButce",
                                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                            return {
                                                value: item
                                            }
                                        }))
                                    },
                                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert(textStatus);
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" id="TipList">
                    $(function () {
                        $("#txtTip").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                var param = { prefixText: $('#txtTip').val() };
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "Default.aspx/GetTip",
                                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                            return {
                                                value: item
                                            }
                                        }))
                                    },
                                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert(textStatus);
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function openModalForm() {
                        window.showModalDialog('Details.aspx', '', 'status:1; resizable:1; dialogWidth:900px; dialogHeight:500px; dialogTop=50px; dialogLeft:100px')
                    }
                </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                function saveData() {
                    //==== Call validateData() Method to perform validation. This method will return 0
                    //==== if validation pass else returns number of validations fails.

                    //var errCount = validateData();

                    //==== If validation pass save the data.


                        var txtButce = $("#txtButce").val();
                        var txtTip = $("#txtTip").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Default.aspx/saveData",
                            data: JSON.stringify({butce:txtButce,tip:txtTip}),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            datatype: "jsondata",
                            async: "true",
                            success: function (response) {
                                $(".errMsg ul").remove();
                                var myObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
                                if (myObject > 0) {

                                    $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Data kaydedildi</li></ul>");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Kayıt işleminde hata olustu, tekrar deneyiniz.</li></ul>");
                                }
                                $(".errMsg").show("slow");
                                clear();
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                            }
                        });

                }
            </script>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <label for="txtButce" >Bütçe Kodu/Lokasyon: </label>
                    <input id="txtButce">
                    <br />
                    <label for="txtTip">Tip/Alttip: </label>
                    <input id="txtTip" />
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateInfo" runat="server" Style="color: White;" /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCalShow" runat="server" Text="Tarih Seçiniz" />
               <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" />

            </div>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPenaltyCalculate" Text="Hesapla" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPenaltySubmit" Text="Kaydet" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
            <%-- %>  <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Haftayı yeniden yükle" style="margin-left:60px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" />
            --%>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: added saveData script that passes parameters to method in codebehind :

Comment: if there is simpler way , please share it here, this way increases complexity. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do another AJAX POST to a `WebMethod` (or asp.net postback) to send the data back to the server which can then update your database.

Comment: Thank you Chris, yes I figured that, so I tried to do something like that:

Comment: No problem. If you post your updated code as an edit onto your question it may help others with similar problems.